# Latex (LyX) /pdftex - Change file name based on file content

Tags: compiling, jobname

When  compile a LaTeX document with pdftex it usually has the name `newfile.pdf`. Is it possible to change the name of my document based on the content in the LaTeX source I'm about to compile ? More precisely, is it possible to insert commands in the LaTeX, so that when I type something along the lines of `\change{name}` in the body of the text and compile, the compiled document automatically has the name `name` ?

Would it help anything, if I would compile the document out of LyX ?

Comment: why don't you save the source with a more meaningful name than `newfile` ??? then the pdf will have same name as your source.

Comment: As it is suggested in David Carlisle's comment, you **can** or even **should** give your document a meaningful name, e.g., Homework-28Aug2015.tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have good reasons to ask this, I think. To be more precise, it has to do with my workflow: I frequently use TeX to generate bits of text, that I incorporate in other (graphical) file using other programs. Thus I usually have my editor open, and only edit parts of the body of my tex file, generate a pdf, then edit again, generate another pdf an so on. always creating a new tex file to suit the name I want my pdfs to have is time consuming - as is the clicking around to save the pdf file with a different name than `newfile`. Of course, these are just seconds, but [...]

Comment: [...] when doing this a lot, it does build up. Being able to change the name of the pdf from within the tex file would save a lot of time at the end of the day.

Comment: If you use Arara to compile, you could add a line with a script to rename the PDF and write the script to take an argument setting the new name.

Comment: @cfr Could you please be a bit more specific about this ?

Comment: @user10324 OK. I've written an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Arara in at least two ways to achieve this.

## Method 1

This is probably the most straightforward and it is cross-platform. It just uses the default Arara configuration - no need to add any additional scripts or rules.

The following code will produce `great-name.pdf` regardless of the name of the `.tex` file itself:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { options: "--jobname great-name" }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

To compile it, you write

```
arara <filename>
```

where `<filename>.tex` is the name of your `.tex` file. Arara then runs `pdflatex --jobname great-name <filename>.tex` and produces `great-name.pdf`.

One thing to bear in mind with this method, is that auxiliary files will also use the specified name. So you'll have `great-name.aux` and `great-name.log` - **not** `<filename>.aux` or `<filename>.log`. This might be an advantage, of course, but it might be a disadvantage and so is worth being aware of.

## Method 2

This is less straightforward and, depending on your requirements, might or might not be preferable. The details are OS-dependent. The following will work for a system where the default shell is `sh` or `bash` or similar. It will likely work for other reasonably POSIX-compliant shells as well. I assume it would not work on Windows, for example.

Here's an additional rule I just wrote which should, I think, rename the PDF on request. Note that I am not conversant with YAML so my Arara scripting abilities are extremely rudimentary.

### *Caveat emptor...*

```
!config
# renamepdf rule for arara
identifier: renamepdf
name: rename PDF
command: <arara> mv -n @{force} @{options} "@{getBasename(file)}.pdf" "@{output}.pdf"
arguments:
- identifier: output
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.output}
  default: <arara> @{getBasename(file).concat("copy")}
- identifier: force
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.force,"-f")}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
# vim: set nospell:
```

This creates a new rule for Arara which you should put in your personal rules directory. Mine is `~/.arara/rules/`. The file should be named `renamepdf.yaml` e.g. mine is `~/.arara/rules/renamepdf.yaml`.

Then you can say, for example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: renamepdf: { output: great-name, force: true, options: "-b" }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

This first runs `pdflatex` and then renames the resulting PDF to `great-name.pdf`. If a file by that name already exists, it overwrites it since `force` is `true`. However, it will first make a backup because the option `-b` is also passed onto the `mv` command. (I just used `-b` as an example - the idea is that the `options` allows any options not explicitly covered by the rule to be passed straight through to the command.)

If you look in the directory of default rules, you will find examples where Arara does one thing on Windows and one thing on other systems. If you want to adapt the above for Windows, therefore, I suggest taking a look there for help. The manual is, obviously, a further source of information.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your knowledgeable answer! Might it be possible to adjust your solution (especially the first one because of it advantages, e.g. as it is easier to use and I can use it on any PC that has `arara` installed, without writing the rules again) so that I can pass the name of the file from the body of the document, i.e. by inserting a command like `\change{great-name}` in the body of the document ?

Comment: @user10324 No. You cannot do that for the reasons David explained. Once compilation starts, `\jobname` is set. Arara needs to know the name *before* compilation begins in order to pass that name to the compilation command.

Answer (score 6):

The normal way to control the output file name is save the input to a suitable name, however web2c tex implementations do have a `--jobname` options

```
 pdflatex --jobname=zzz newfile.tex
```

will produce `zzz.pdf` I don't think you can set this within the file, as the jobname is frozen once tex starts the log.

Comment: As I don't have a good knowledge how all the technical parts of LaTeX work together to produce the final outcome, does your answer mean, that it also can't be done using the `arara` compiler that was suggested by another user ? As far as I understood the issue, `arara` is using itself pdflatex, so if pdflatex doesn't allow it, that's the end of it ? (Would perhaps be alternatives to pdflatex that allow this ? I could also compile to dvi. )

Comment: @user10324 No because Arara can pass options with arguments to the compiler. So you can have a line telling Arara to run `pdflatex --jobname=<argument here> filename` rather than just `pdflatex`. This is how it already works for other options passed to the compiler by Arara e.g. for shell escape or synchronisation.