# Automatically Change the File Output name

Tags: pdftex, winedt, output

**Background:** I'm writing an exam and solutions for the exam in LaTeX (using WinEdt 10.2, if that matters). The university has an exam package I'm using that lets me change one option on the package to declare if I want to include solutions or not each time I compile.

The downside is that the filename remains the same, so what I have been doing is compiling *with* the answers. Then I'll locate the file in the directory and manually change the name of the file, then I can go back to the .tex file, change my option to *not* include solutions, then compile again and I'll have produced a blank copy of the test.

All of this isn't too bad, it is just a bit more cumbersome than I care for and I'd like to make the process slightly more efficient.

I was looking [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3021) and noticed this OP has the same question as me. However, the answers posted here didn't work for me (or I don't know how to implement them). I tried placing "pdflatex -job-name=name" both before and after declaring document class, but it didn't seem to help.

> **Question:** Is there a command to easily change an output's filename from within a .tex file to avoid having to navigate to the file and manually changing the name?

If it will help, I can post an MWE, but since my issue isn't dealing with something compiling incorrectly, I won't begin with posting one.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263621/latex-lyx-pdftex-change-file-name-based-on-file-content